# Who runs Maven Central and why is there a delay before repository updates are available?

Tags: java, maven-2

According to [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/maven-gae-plugin/issues/detail?id=96), the `maven-gae-plugin` released an update and it took several hours before this was available from **Maven Central**.

Who runs **Maven Central** and what causes this delay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maven central is handled by maven developers (Apache).

And it takes time to check if the new version of an artifact respects some conventions given by apache.

As said on maven.apache.org

> The [..] process is mostly automated with turnaround time averaging 1 Business day.

---

**Resources :**

- [maven.apache.org - Guide to uploading artifacts to the Central Repository](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html)
- [sonatype.org - Central Sync Requirements](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Central+Sync+Requirements)
- [sonatype.org - Uploading 3rd-party Artifacts to Maven Central](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Uploading+3rd-party+Artifacts+to+Maven+Central)

Comment: Central does a pull so there is a delay from the actual release until it's pulled in.

Comment: As a workaround, you can pull jitpack.io releases within seconds after tagging your stuff on github. 

Honestly, maven and maven central and the ecosystem around it needs some shaking up. All the checks are automated. All this is is bureaucracy. There's no good technical reason for stuff to be this convoluted, slow, and tedious. Just about every other package manager out there works in seconds using a very straightforward process.

Comment: I might also add that this is not really correct ... Maven-Central is run by Sonatype (The company that built the software behind Maven-Central) ... Apache is also running it's "Apache-Central" repository.apache.org (not actually an official term) which newer Maven versions seem to be using as default.